# Hive - How to combine many tables having the same appendix?

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to combine many tables selected according to the year. For the current year (`2019`), I have `tab_h_2016`, `tab_h_2017` & `tab_h_2018`. When We'll be in 2020, we will add `tab_h_2019`. How Can I join (using union) all the tables having the same appendix in a way that if a new table is added to the database, the table is automatically combined?

Comment: Are all the tables having same schema?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate table names in the shell and parametrize your script.

Shell:

```
table1=$(date +"tab_h_%Y" --date " -3 year");
table2=$(date +"tab_h_%Y" --date " -2 year");
table3=$(date +"tab_h_%Y" --date " -1 year");

hive --hiveconf table1="$table1"  --hiveconf table2="$table2"  --hiveconf table3="$table3" -f your_script.hql
```

Script `your_script.hql`:

```
select * from ${hiveconf:table1} inner join ${hiveconf:table2} ...
```